# Proof that Dempster-Shafer Normalised rule is Associative

Tags: artificial-intelligence

[image: All the theory about this rule]

Hint: I know it is associative and I just need a proof: (m1 ⊕ m2 ) ⊕ m3 = m1 ⊕ (m2 ⊕ m3) that will show that the operation "⊕" is associative. Thank you in advance!

operation "x" in the image is multiplication!

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)).

Comment: You still haven't defined $\oplus$, as far as I can see.  Also, please ask only one question per post.  Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.